# History tracking with JPA

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jpa

I would like to implement history tracking/auditing for one of my model entities by using a new table to store a log with the user who made the change, the date, and whatever changed in each update/insert.

I'm using EclipseLink as my JPA provider, but I don't want to use its [History Policy](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Configuring_a_Descriptor_%28ELUG%29#Configuring_a_History_Policy)  because the provider can change in the future. I can't either use [Hibernate Envers](http://www.jboss.org/envers) for the same reason.

I looked into the [auditing support which Spring Data provides](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-jpa/docs/current/reference/html/jpa.repositories.html#jpa.auditing), but it seems very basic and it only allows you to store the user who created or modified the entity and the dates, not the changes.

I also know about JPA's `prePersist` and `preUpdate`, but the specificacion says that:

> In general, the lifecycle method of a portable application should not
>   invoke EntityManager or Query operations, access other entity
>   instances, or modify relationships within the same persistence
>   context.

Is there a clean, easy and portable way to implement this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have made that manually, with a separate EJB service, whose responsibility was to extract history data and save it as a MAP. It is very rudimentary in which only basic data and the IDs of relationships are saved, but that was enough for my case.

Basically I was inspecting the persistent properties with a bit of reflection.

Comment: Thank you Andrei, I'll try something like that