# Java Framework to maintain entity history automatically

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I am working on a project where I need to create history of particular table automatically. I have used `@Audited` annotation for it but it's creating duplicate data in table.
I am running out of space due to duplicate data.Even EclipseLink is not sloving my problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [History tracking with JPA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20216946/history-tracking-with-jpa)

Comment: So what's wrong with having duplicate data? Are you running out of space?

Comment: @Kayaman- Yes, Extra space is issue for me.

Answer (score 1):

Please check [Hibernate Envers](https://hibernate.org/orm/envers/).
This component integrates with JPA and Hibernate, and takes care of maintaing a revision history for any @Audited annotated Entity.

There are some guides on the net:

- [Maintain the data versioning info with Spring Data — Envers](https://medium.com/@denuwanhimangahettiarachchi/maintain-the-data-versioning-info-with-spring-data-envers-42b6dfc19e27)
- [Spring Boot : How to add JPA and Hibernate Envers Auditing](https://developerpod.com/2020/01/21/spring-boot-how-to-add-jpa-hibernate-envers-auditing/)
- [Spring Boot + Hibernate + Hibernate Envers](https://github.com/adamzareba/company-structure-hibernate-history)

Comment: while it's great to link to an answer, you should also provide some details inline.

Answer (score 0):

You tagged your question with Hibernate, but if switching to Eclipselink would be an option for you, be sure to check out the [History Policy feature](https://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/History) of Eclipselink. It allows automatic historization of data.